# Install openstack

Tags: ubuntu, openstack

While installing openstack, in Ubuntu 14.04 I am getting the following error

```
chinmay123@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install openstack
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
```

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

> ```
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>  openstack : Depends: juju-core but it is not going to be installed
>              Depends: libvirt-bin but it is not going to be installed
>              Depends: pollinate but it is not going to be installed
>              Depends: python-neutronclient but it is not installable
>              Depends: python-openstackclient but it is not installable
>              Depends: python3-bson but it is not installable
>              Depends: python3-jinja2 but it is not installable
>              Depends: python3-kombu but it is not going to be installed
>              Depends: python3-mock but it is not installable
>              Depends: python3-nose but it is not installable
>              Depends: python3-passlib but it is not installable
>              Depends: python3-requests-oauthlib but it is not installable
>              Depends: python3-ws4py but it is not installable
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
> chinmay123@ubuntu:~$
> ```

I am not sure why I am getting this, Please guide me on how to proceed.

Comment: You may not have the proper repository, you need to add it, like shown in the guide (this is the Openstack Kilo guide): http://docs.openstack.org/kilo/install-guide/install/apt/content/ch_basic_environment.html#basics-prerequisites 
Check the part called "To enable the OpenStack repository"

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the system may be trying to install the newest repositories meant for Ubuntu Xenial (16.04) - i.e OpenStack Newton. The easiest way around would be to use a 16.04 Ubuntu to run the install.

You could add the Mitaka respository using

`sudo add-apt-repository cloud-archive:mitaka`

Otherwise, you can install it by using the commands (after adding th cloud-installer stable repository (Please remove any other repository that you may have installed)

`sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:cloud-installer/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y openstack
sudo openstack-install --version
sudo openstack-install`

Please let me know if this helps

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this message because there are unmet dependencies.

You have many options.

1. Manually install the dependencies using `apt`

   This is the hardest way to deal with the problem as your dependencies may also have dependencies, but you can see what you'd need to install right in the error message.
2. `sudo gdebi package.deb` to use this package manager which also fetches dependencies (or the GUI version `gdebi-gtk`)
3. If you use `apt` but have missing dependencies you can try to fix it with `sudo apt-get -f install`
4. I'm quoting OpenStack's website, I don't know much about this solution but it sounds promising:

> Canonical’s Ubuntu Cloud archive allows users the ability to install
>   newer releases of OpenStack on Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS (and the
>   dependencies) as they become available up through the next Ubuntu LTS
>   release (presumably 14.04).

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/CloudArchive for more details.

I would start with #3 since you already ran `apt`.